# Unicode in string is giving problems for replacement

Tags: r, regex

I am working with strings in `R`. My issue rises with a special character that is not allowing to replace the strings properly. I do some replacement to extract a text between `__` and `_` but it is not working for last examples. The code is next:

```
#Extract
y$Extract <- gsub(".*[_]{2}([^_]+)[_].*", "\\1",gsub('\n\n','_',y$Var))
```

The data used is:

```
#Data
y <- structure(list(Var = c("\n\n\nEl sector turístico en Mexico: análisis de la incidencia de la pandemia de la Covid-19 en el margen bruto, y propuesta de mejora para los hoteles 5 estrellas ubicados en la provincia de Taco, cantón Taco, parroquia GX\n\n                    <U+FEFF> \n                \n\n\n\nCabezas Vásquez, Dayanna Gabriela\n (UNAM - TEC, 2022-07-01)\n\nLa presencia del Coronavirus sin duda ha provocado desestabilización en uno de los sectores más perjudicados, que es el hotelero, ya que cuando hubo la pandemia, en Ecuador y en todo el mundo, se tomaron medidas de ...\n\n", 
"\n\n\nAnálisis de costos y rentabilidad años 2018 al 2020 para industrias manufactureras de tamaño grande con mayores ingresos orientados a mercados regionales, subsector elaboración de productos alimenticios y bebidas en Mexico\n\n                    <U+FEFF> \n                \n\n\n\nAlbarracín Cedeño, Madelaine Nicole\n (ITAM - CAS, 2022-06-01)\n\nEl presente trabajo de titulación se enfoca en analizar los costos y rentabilidad de los años 2018  al  2020  para  industrias  manufactureras  de  tamaño  grande  con  mayores  ingresos orientados a mercados regionales, ...\n\n", 
"\n\n\nPlan de negocios para la implementación de una empresa de asesoría de bodas ubicada en el Distrito Mexicano\n\n                    <U+FEFF> \n                \n\n\n\nAndrade Totoy, Gabriela Abigail\n (ITAM, 2022-06-01)\n\nEste trabajo tiene como objetivo la realización de un plan de negocios dentro del mundo de la planificación de bodas y el asesoramiento que se podría brindar dentro de la cuidad de  Mexico.  Dentro  de  este  trabajo  se  ...\n\n", 
"\n\n\nDiseño de un sistema de gestión de la calidad basado en la norma Iso 9001:2008 para los procesos relacionados con el cliente en la empresa la Competencia S.A.\n\n                    <U+FEFF> \n                \n\n\nCadena Echeverría, Jaime Luis Hermel* (TEC, 2014)\n\nEn el presente trabajo se ha diseñado la documentación requerida para un sistema de\r\ngestión de la calidad basado en la Norma ISO 9001:2008 de los procesos relacionados con\r\nel cliente de la empresa La Competencia S.A., ...\n\n", 
"\n\n\nDiseño e implementación de un modelo de marketing basado en estrategias para un crecimiento continuo, con innovación y financiamiento para la Empresa Jocotours Cia. Ltda., en el Distrito Mexicano para el año 2015\n\n                    <U+FEFF> \n                \n\n\nSánchez García, Roberto  Carlos* (TEC, 2015)\n\nLa empresa Jocotours fue creada en el año 2010 con el propósito de mejorar el turismo de su organización relacionada Fundación de Conservación Jocotoco, una entidad que se dedica a la conservación de las aves amenazadas ...\n\n", 
"\n\n\nPlan de negocios para la explotación técnica, ecónomica y ecológica de una mina de agregados pétreos en la parroquia de Chilos\n\n                    <U+FEFF> \n                \n\n\nAutor desconocido (TEC / 2011, 2011-03)\n\nEl presente trabajo de disertación de desenvuelve como un proyecto de gestión de riesgos y salud ocupacional de la TEC, el cual abarca la implementación, desarrollo, manteniemiento y control del sistema de gestión de ...\n\n"
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

But the output for final three rows is wrong (sorry for image, print is too large):

[image]

It should be similar to first rows with the names and year. I think the unicode is doing something to text and I do not know how to solve it.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using multiple `gsub`, we could extract if the pattern is similar across the elements - here the pattern matched is one or more characters (`.*`) till the unicode character (`<U+..>`) followed by one or more spaces (`\\s+`), newlines (`\\n+`) another set of space, newline (`\\s+\\n+`), then match the characters that are not a closing bracket (`[^)]+`) followed by a closing bracket (`\\)`) and capture those within `(...)`).  In the `replacement`, specify the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured substring

```
sub(".*\\<U\\+[^>]+>\\s+\n+\\s+\\n+([^)]+\\))\n.*", "\\1", y$Var)
[1] "Cabezas Vásquez, Dayanna Gabriela\n (UNAM - TEC, 2022-07-01)" 
[2]  "Albarracín Cedeño, Madelaine Nicole\n (ITAM - CAS, 2022-06-01)"
[3] "Andrade Totoy, Gabriela Abigail\n (ITAM, 2022-06-01)"   
[4] "Cadena Echeverría, Jaime Luis Hermel* (TEC, 2014)"             
[5] "Sánchez García, Roberto  Carlos* (TEC, 2015)"   
[6] "Autor desconocido (TEC / 2011, 2011-03)"
```

Or can be also

```
sub(".*\n{2,}([^(]+[()][^)]+\\)).*", "\\1", y$Var)
[1] "Cabezas Vásquez, Dayanna Gabriela\n (UNAM - TEC, 2022-07-01)"  
[2] "Albarracín Cedeño, Madelaine Nicole\n (ITAM - CAS, 2022-06-01)"
[3] "Andrade Totoy, Gabriela Abigail\n (ITAM, 2022-06-01)"      
[4] "Cadena Echeverría, Jaime Luis Hermel* (TEC, 2014)"             
[5] "Sánchez García, Roberto  Carlos* (TEC, 2015)"      
[6] "Autor desconocido (TEC / 2011, 2011-03)"
```